# PhoneGap/Cordova Push GeoLocation from localStorage vars to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, cordova

I have a Cordova/Phonegap App that pushes geolocation (longitude/latitude) to localStorage. Im having a problem getting those variables to push into mySQL database. I am simply trying to send the data upon connection to mySQL. My code looks like:

**index.html (geoLocation settings)**

```
    //find location info//
    function geolocation(){
        var options = enableHighAccuracy = true;
      watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

    //this functions runs if geolocation is returned//
        function onSuccess(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            //save to local storage
            localStorage.setItem("latitude", lat);
            localStorage.setItem("longitude", lng);
            //tell user their lng and lat
            //alert("lat: " + lat + "long: " + lng);
        }
        //if cant get location give error//
        function onError(error) {
            alert("message: " + error.message);
            localStorage.setItem("message", error.message);
         }
        }
    geolocation();
```

Works fine in my  sending data to localStorage. Now all i need to do is onNetworkAvailable, push the data to mySQL.

**My ondevice.js (referenced in my head)**

```
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0) {
          document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
    }
      }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods

var isNetworkAvailable=true;

function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
    document.addEventListener("offline", setOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", setOnline, false);
     }

     function checkConnection() {
         var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

     var states = {};
     states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
     states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
     states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
     states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
     states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
     states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
     states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

     alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
     }

 function networkAvailable() {
      return isNetworkAvailable;

     //var userID = $(this).attr('id');
    var getlat = window.localStorage.getItem("latitude", lat);
    var getlng = window.localStorage.getItem("longitude", lng);
     //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'myurl/dbUserLocation.php',
                data: { getlat : getlat, getlng : getlng},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("Data sent!");
                },
        complete:function remove(){
        localStorage.removeItem("latitude");
        localStorage.removeItem("longitude");
        },
        error: function(){
        alert('Code 303A');
        }
                });
            }

    function setOffline() {
             isNetworkAvailable=false;
    }

    function setOnline() {
            isNetworkAvailable=true;
    }
```

**And my dbUserLocation.php to send to mySQL:**

```
      ini_set('display_errors',1); 
      error_reporting(E_ALL);

      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

      $hostdb = 'myhostip';
      $namedb = 'mydbname';
      $userdb = 'root';
      $passdb = 'mydbpass';

      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=dbip; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

      if(isset($_POST['longitude']) && ($_POST['latitude'])) {

      $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
      $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];

      $stmt = "INSERT INTO row_location (latitude,longitude) 
               VALUES (:longitude,:latitude)";

      $q = $conn->prepare($stmt);
      $results = $q->execute(array(
        ":longitude"=>$longitude,
        ":latitude"=>$latitude
     ));
      }
      exit();
```

Like stated, my longitude and latitude stores to the DB with no problem. But getting it to send to my mySQL db is what im having trouble doing. I am using this method because I am developing for mobile (Cordova/Phonegap to be exact).

Any help with this would be a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has an issue sending localStorage coords...I was able to get my data to send... i set up my ajax to POST my new vars which referenced Cordova/Phonegaps getItem from localStorage. My code is as follows... works perfect! Hope this helps anyone trying to achieve the same thing.

```
    var getlat = window.localStorage.getItem("latitude");
    var getlng = window.localStorage.getItem("longitude");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http:myurl/dbUserLocation.php',
        data: { latitude : getlat, longitude : getlng },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("Location Data Sent!");
        },
        complete:function remove(){
            localStorage.removeItem("latitude");
            localStorage.removeItem("longitude");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Code 303A');
        }
    });
```